# JAVA Max Value from a String that contains only digits

Tags: java

I have some problem with an exercise from geeksforgeeks portal. I don't know why they say to me wrong answer. I have completed the function and my results on their visible test cases is good. Maybe i don't understand what they want from me to solve in the problem? Can you help me please?

The problem is this [image]

My code is this:

```
//Your Code here
   long answer = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
   {
       long multiply = (str.charAt(i) - 48) * answer;
       long sum = (str.charAt(i) - 48) + answer;

       if (multiply > sum)
           answer = multiply;
       else if (sum > multiply)
       answer = sum;
   }
   System.out.println(answer);
```

And as you can see... my solution works for the visible test cases:
[image]

Important!!! They don't show the input test cases where the code have failed. They don't show any input of the test cases.

EDITED:
some request of custom input to show (also changed a little the if else statement... included now the possibility of equals sum and multiply

[image]

Comment: Maybe your code is failing one (or more) of their secret tests?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic because questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: why to close my question? I'm just asking for some help... I tried by myself all possible solutions and now I'm with no option to test and try (no chance to solve this) ... I need little help from other people cause I don't see what I am doing wrong? :(((

Comment: We expect to see an input which reproduces your issue, the expected output, why this output is expected, and the actual output.  You have provided none of these things.

Comment: i provided in question pictures with input ... but i will put another picture with some of custom inputs and outputs of my code...

Comment: We need an input that produces a wrong answer.  We also need the expected and actual outputs for that input, with the differences clearly indicated.

Comment: i don't know that.. because they don't show the inputs they use for test cases :((

Comment: In that case, we cannot help you, because we don't know them either.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a small bug due to the following if-else statements:

```
if (multiply > sum)
    answer = multiply;
else if (sum > multiply)
    answer = sum;
```

You forgot the condition when sum equals multiply. In that case, your answer variable remains unchanged in that iteration and you will get a wrong answer finally.

Now sum == multiply can occur for the test case of "22" --> your code gives answer as 2, while the answer should be 4.

This might be one of the test cases failing for your code.

Comment: thank you... good point, but i tryed like this... and also say to me wrong answer :( what other test cases could be the hidden? If I understand well...could me problem only here on test cases?

Comment: //Your Code here
       long answer = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
       {
           long multiply = (str.charAt(i) - 48) * answer;
           long sum = (str.charAt(i) - 48) + answer;
           
           if (multiply > sum)
           answer = multiply;
           else if (sum > multiply)
           answer = sum;
           else if (multiply == sum)
           answer = multiply;
       }
       System.out.println(answer);